# Prevent zoom reset when using manipulate with Graphics3D

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d

I am creating a series of "apps" as study aids for the Engineering Statics course that I teach. I am usually able to solve most of my "problems", but I am stuck on a simple one. The code below allows a user to visualize a 3D force vector that has its position controlled with two angles, a1 rotates the plane that contains the line of action of the vector about the z-axis and b1 rotates the vector out of the xy-plane.

The user can use the mouse to rotate (LMB), pan (Shift+LMB) and zoom (Ctrl+LMB) the graphics. When the user adjusts the manipulate sliders the rotation and pan settings remain unchanged, but the graphic "snaps" back the the default zoom setting. I would like to prevent the zoom reset.

I am sure that I am missing something simple, but I have been unable to find a post that mentions this issue. If someone has a solution, I would greatly appreciate it if they would pass it along.

A second small issue... does anyone know how I could add the degree symbol to the label of the slider?

```
cd[x_] := Cos[x*\[Pi]/180.0];
sd[x_] := Sin[x*\[Pi]/180.0];
r = 10;
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{
   Style[InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], 
FaceForm[{LightGray, Opacity[0.2]}]],
   Style[HalfPlane[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {cd[a1 ], sd[a1 ], 0}], 
FaceForm[{LightGray, Opacity[0.2]}]],
   Style[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 
  f*{cd[b1 ] cd[a1], cd[b1] sd[a1], sd[b1]}}], Black, Thick],
   Style[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, f*{cd[b1 ] cd[a1], cd[b1] sd[a1], sd[b1]}],
 Opacity[0.01], EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, Gray]]],
   },
  PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {-r, r}},
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  BoxRatios -> {4, 4, 3},
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic",
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  Method -> {"RotationControl" -> Dynamic@"Globe"}
  ],
 Control[{{a1, 30, "\[Theta]"}, 0, 360, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
ControlType -> Slider}],
 Control[{{b1, 30, "\[Phi]"}, -90, 90, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
ControlType -> Slider}],
 Control[{{f, 10, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(F\), \(mag\)]\)"}, 1, 10, 
Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlType -> Slider}],
 TrackedSymbols :> {a1, b1, f}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best solution in this case will be to not recreate whole `Graphics3D` when th slider is manipulated. It can be done by simply adding `Dynamic` to the primitives inside (lookup 'nesting dynamic' to learn more).

Like so:

```
... Style[ Dynamic @ HalfPlane[...
```

> A second small issue... does anyone know how I could add the degree symbol to the label of the slider?

You can provide your controller layout explicitly, e.g.:

```
Control[
  {{a1, 30, "θ"}, 0, 360, Row[{Slider[##], Spacer[5], #, Degree}] &}
]
```